# Vector recycling with Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, vector, vectorization, rcpp

I'm trying to get vector recycling to work in Rcpp.

```
> recycle_and_add <- Rcpp::cppFunction("
+ NumericVector recycle_and_add(NumericVector x, NumericVector y) {
+     return x + y;
+ }")
> recycle_and_add(42, 1:5)
[1] 43
```

I'm expecting it to return something like

```
> 42 + 1:5
[1] 43 44 45 46 47
```

After some analysis, I found out that `x.size()` is `1` and `y.size()` is `5` within the Rcpp function, so clearly vector recycling doesn't work out-of-the-box.

While I can manually find the longest of `x` and `y` and recycle the shorter one, in the actual application there are 3 or 4 arguments requiring recycling, so I can imagine manual unrolling would result in a lot of variables pointing to different vectors and turn the code into a pile of spaghetti.

Does Rcpp have any built-in support for vector recycling, like, with some sugar?

Comment: Unroll your vectors in R before calling into C++. The easiest way to do this is by calling `data.frame`.

Comment: Re-read some documentation. You are under the mistaken assumption Rcpp would magically recycle for you.  When you pass 42 to `NumericVector` you get _exactly_ that: a one-element numeric vector containing 42.

Comment: You can use `rep_len()` like in R.

Comment: @HongOoi Thank, that sounds easy, but I'm not sure if the performance penalty is negligible. Also just for the record, are you suggesting me to use `df <- data.frame(arg1=arg1, arg2=arg2)`, and then `.Call("_myPackage_myFunction", df$arg1, df$arg2)`?

Answer (score 4):

Strategy-wise, it's almost always easier to recycle in *R* and then move into *C++*.

If it *must* be done in *C++*, then the following design pattern should work:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector recycle_vector(Rcpp::NumericVector x, 
                             Rcpp::NumericVector y) {

    // Obtain vector sizes
    int n_x = x.size();
    int n_y = y.size(); 

    // Check both vectors have elements
    if(n_x <= 0 || n_y <= 0) {
        Rcpp::stop("Both `x` and `y` vectors must have at least 1 element.");
    }

    // Compare the three cases that lead to recycling... 
    if(n_x == n_y) {
        return x + y;
    } else if (n_x > n_y) {
        return Rcpp::rep_len(y, n_x) + x;
    }

    return Rcpp::rep_len(x, n_y) + y; 
}
```

Test Cases:

```
recycle_vector(1:3, 1:3)
# [1] 2 4 6
recycle_vector(4, 1:3)
# [1] 5 6 7
recycle_vector(10:12, -2:-1)
# [1] 8 10 10
```